# VBA copy a chart worksheet from a template

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have a worksheet chart that I want to use as a template in a macro.  I am trying to copy the sheet and assign it to an object of type chart but can't get it to work.

Below in the code are two lines of working code to either create or copy a chart sheet.

The problem comes from the last line of code.  It copies the sheet but then errors before it goes to the next line (error 424 object required).

Can anyone explain why this is happening and a solution to assign the sheet on one line.

Right now my solution is to copy the template then set WS_chart3 to the activesheet, I just don't like references to the active sheet if I can avoid them.

```
Sub test()

Dim WS_chart2 As Chart
Dim WS_chart3 As Chart

    'adds chart sheet but doesn't use a template
    Set WS_chart2 = Charts.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))

    'adds sheet but doesn't asign in to variable WS_chart2
    Sheets("template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

    'adds chart sheet but then errors out
    Set WS_chart3 = Sheets("template").Copy(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

One problem for sure is that the Copy method does not return an object (it doesn't return anything), so you have to first make the copy and then get the new sheet and assign it to the variable.

I think you can just do

```
Dim SheetBeforeChart3 As Long

SheetBeforeChart3 = Sheets.Count
Sheets("template").Copy After:=Sheets(SheetBeforeChart3)

Set WS_chart3 = Sheets(SheetBeforeChart3 + 1)
```

I don't really know Excel VBA though, there might be other problems, I hopes this helps you a little all the same.

Comment: Yeah thats similar to what I did `template.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)`
    `Set WS_chart = ActiveSheet`  Your way has the benefit of not relying on the active sheet.  Will give it a bit longer to see if any other suggestions come up.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Office 2013: In the indexing order the new sheet is at position 1, but its naming suggests to be after the template.